# Questions about plane electromagnetic wave

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

A wavefront is defined to be the locus of all points on which the field oscillations are in phase, in the plane electromagnetic wavefront, it is said that all points on a plane perpendicular to the direction of propagation have the same magnitude of $ \vec E $ & $ \vec B$

[image]

If this wave has an amplitude $A$ , then it has a maximum value which it cannot exceed, then how come all the points on the plane have the same field magnitude?

What I'm saying is, stick a plane perpendicular to that picture and you will observe that the $ E$ & $B$ fields have a finite range, am I misunderstanding the concept?

Edit: Plane wavefronts such as these that are perpendicular to the axis of motion, if my question is not clear enough maybe you can try to explain what you know about plane wavefronts and where exactly is $E$ or $B$ constant everywhere on the plane, thanks.

[image]

Comment: No, they are not the same. The electric field is $c$ times as high as the magnetic field, where $c$ is the speed of light. But anyway, what are you trying to understand?

Comment: No that's not what I'm saying, I'm saying the values of $E$ are said to be the same on every point on the plane wavefront (same goes for $B$ which is a constant multiple of $E$, yes) What I'm trying to understand is how can the plane contain points where the values of $E$ are the same everywhere even though $E$ vanishes when it reaches its maximum amplitude $A$?

Comment: "...the values of  E  are the same everywhere even though E vanishes when it reaches its maximum amplitude A..." because it is oscillating in time and for a fixed time instant in space along the axis of propagation between $-A$ and $A$.

Comment: I figured out my problem, these arrows are indicating the strength of the $E$ field which changes in the $ \hat z$ direction but the $E$ field itself is in the direction of $ ± \hat j$. Thank you.